# ASP.Net MVC OAuthWebSecurity Authentication for Google Plus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 application and am taking advantage of MVC's OAuthWebSecurity to incorporate OAuth providers for authentication.  My app needs to be able to access an authenticated user's friends.  I'm able to do this successfully with Facebook and Twitter.  My next challenge is to use OAuthWebSecurity's GoogleClient for authentication.  Is it possible to access Google Plus via the results received from OAuthWebSecurity's GoogleClient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google+ REST API does not currently provide a way for you to access a list of connections for a person. You can see the methods that are available regarding `people` at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/